# Jest tests failing on CI Server

Tags: ts-jest

I have a ts project with tests and Jest as the runner.  Tests run fine locally.

However checking in and running on the CI server (Azure Devops) - the test fails (I have just one at the moment as I get the CI/CD pipeline built out):

[image]

The test in question
[image]

My tsconfig.json
[image]

the jest confg:
[image]

package.json

[image]

Comment: Try setting your `target` to `es5`.

Comment: that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

so I am not entirely sure why this matters - but I basically moved the jest.config.js file (got rid of it) and added the jest configuration to my package.json.

That fixed this.

[image]